# SP2013 CQWP and slider give me blank slides

Tags: 2013, xslt, item-styles

I have a big issue and a question about CQWP and slider.
I have an image library which will serve as a news library. I've set a CQWP on my homepage which will display Image, title and comments columns, and give the proper url link.

So, **first, the question** : how to know which column name should i use? I don't ge thow to use the column names in xsl templates.

Because for the comments, i wrote in my ItemStyle.xsl :

```
<xsl:variable name="DisplayDesc"><xsl:value-of select="@Comments"/></xsl:variable>
<!-- some more code for displaying title...-->
<b><xsl:value-of select="$DisplayDesc" disable-output-esacping="yes"/></b>
```

And nothing of my comment is displayed.

Now, i have a **serious issue** :

i've used Flexslider to set up my slideshow.
For the moment, i have only two images to show, Image1, and Image2.
But my slider displays in order : Image1,Image2,Image1 and a blank slide.

I don't know where this come from, either why Image1 is cloned.

here is my html output, copied on IE developper tool : [image: HTML output from IE developper tool]

Here are the code i've used :
To launch flexslider :

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation:"slide",
  controlNav:false,
  prevText:"précédent",
  nextText:"suivant",
  minItems:1,
  maxItems:20,
  itemWidth:400
});
```

My custom template, which i've declared in myItemStyle.xsl

```
<xsl:template name="HomePage-Slider" match="Row[@Style='HomePage-Slider']" mode="itemstyle">

<xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl"><xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink"><xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/></xsl:call-template></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="SafeImageUrl"><xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeStaticUrl"><xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'ImageUrl'"/></xsl:call-template></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle"><xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle"><xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/><xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/></xsl:call-template></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="DisplayDesc"><xsl:value-of select="@Comments"/></xsl:variable>

<li>
<a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}">
<xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'"><xsl:attribute name="onclick"><xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'"><xsl:attribute name="onclick"><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
<img src="{$SafeImageUrl}" title="{@DisplayTitle}">
<xsl:if test="$ImageWidth != ''"><xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="$ImageWidth" /></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$ImageHeight != ''"><xsl:attribute name="height"><xsl:value-of select="$ImageHeight" /></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
</img>
</a>
<p class="flex-caption">
<!--<xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>-->
<b><xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/></b>
<b><xsl:value-of select="$DisplayDesc" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></b>
</p>
</li>
</xsl:template>
```

Could you help me with these please?
I'm quite desperate at this point..

Comment: Answer to your **first question** is: You need to consider Static name of the column name in the XSL file.  For **Second Issue**: Have you checked that any empty item is there on the list? without any image? As far as I know flexslider automatically render two extra `li` elements with class `clone`, and it is appearing on the your given DOM. It seems that your display template is being called more than one time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Pro.. ! For the **first question**, How do i know/discover this static name? I can't install CAMLQuery helper on my client's device...
**Second issue** : I have only two items in my image library, and these are filled both with an image... Do you think the "clone" items will disappear if i add more items? Maybe for the preoper rendering, i have to use 4 at minima... But there's nothing on Flexslider's doc...

Comment: **First**: when you edit column by going into list settings and edit column. You will find querystring **Field**, the value of it is considered as a static name. **Second**: `clone` will automatically appear when the flexslider jquery plugin will initialize. There should be no matter of   item count. Also check you have not given SharePoint class `dfwp-item` in `li` element, though it is rendering. So it might be the case that some other template is being called as well.

Comment: First : i found it myself finally, but thanks again for confirmation. (was helped by [link]https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/75ca6fab-56f3-4bf4-aae0-2d29821778a2/how-to-get-internal-names-of-columns-in-sharepoint-lists )
The column is "_Comments" and not "Comments" as i wrote.
Second: thanks for the clues, i'll check on it!
You're really helpful @Pro.. !

Comment: Welcome Gaelle! I am Glad, you are getting your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Might be there is some special or html markup to default Title. I have seen you have written `disable-output-escaping='yes'`. But it is not working for special characters. You have to write code to remove these special symbols and html tags.